# Hibernate: Map Two Columns to a HashMap's Key and Value

Tags: java, hibernate, hashmap, annotations, mapping

I have a database with an object, which has translations.

There are 2 tables: table Object which has `id` and more properties and table 'object_translation' which has `object_id`, `language` (varchar) and `translation` (varchar)

I would like to map this to

```
public class Object {
    private Map<Language, String> translations
}
```

Where language is an enum in code and a string in the DB.

Is this possible with annotations? or do I need to create either `Collection<QuestionTranslation>` or write my own hibernate mapping functions in the DAO (I'm using spring-data, so I would prefer to keep it nice and clean as interfaces and annotations)

Versions: spring-boot 2 with provided hibernate from spring-boot-starter:

```
spring boot: <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
<hibernate.version>5.2.17.Final</hibernate.version>
<hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.version>1.0.2.Final</hibernate-jpa-2.1-api.version>
```

So far I have this:

```
@OneToMany
@JoinTable(name = "object_translation", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "object_id", referencedColumnName = "id")})
@MapKey(name = "language")
@MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Map<Language, String> translations;
```

But how do I map the value as well? (for clarification: the String value should be the translation column in the DB)

Because I don't have a primary-key, this should theoretically be possible?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Map<Language, String> - Assuming Language is an ENUM, what column should map to String ?

Comment: The translation column from the join table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to fix it =)

You shouldn't use `@OneToMany`.

What I used:

```
public class Object {

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "object_translation",
                 foreignKey = @ForeignKey(value = ConstraintMode.CONSTRAINT, name = "fk_object_translation_object"),
                 joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "object_id"))
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "language", nullable = false)
    @MapKeyEnumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "translation", nullable = false)
    private Map<Language, String> translations;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not achievable from ORM perspective. There is no way to tell ORM framework to map String to Translation column.

The best way to achieve this would be by retrieving the rows from Object_Translation as a List or Set using @OneToMany or @ManyToMany with mappedBy and then writing your custom to convert them to a map.

Comment: so your answer is basically: It's not possible with annotations, you need to write your own DAO with a mapping from and to the entity?

Comment: If you are planning to write the custom code in DAO , then yes. I personally prefer writing such code in my entity itself.

Comment: Wouldn't `@CollectionTable` with `@Column` work? I'll try it out

Comment: @CollectionTable  is to retrieve a list of values instead of objects based on a JoinColumn. For e.g. if you would like to retrieve all the values of translation for a particular object_id without getting the "language", then you can use it. But not for what you have described you wish to achieve.

Comment: Works like a charm =)